# Two drop-down menus in Intellij are confusing

Tags: android, flutter, intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide, virtual-device-manager

There are two drop-downs:

[image]

I really cannot figure out why where are two drop-downs - one is for just Android, one is for Flutter projects? When I hit that green play button, then which one is it going to launch? Super confusing.

Comment: As per your image 1st dropdown is your  **connected mobile device** to your system (Device like your Simulator), and 2nd dropdown is your **Run configuration files**. if you run flutter project then by default _main.dart_ file has been selected, when you can run the application on clicking the green play button that time _main.dart_ file is been runing.

Comment: there are 3 drop-downs, not 2 - and I am still not sure why there are 3

Answer (score 1):

In the menu File | Project Structure | Modules, please remote the module named like `xxx_android`(no file will be deleted).

Another way you may right-click on the main toolbar, and select Customize Toolbar to remove the Android device selector button.

Comment: I cannot disable Android without also disabling Flutter and vice versa - seems strange

Comment: Ah, I didn't notice that the developers in Google forced the user must install the Android plugin recently. I've updated my answer.